# Is it possible to "hot reload" a ASP.NET Core application without pressing pause and continue?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, hot-reload

The **hot reload** of code changes in DotNet Core / Visual Studio works perfect.

The only disadvantage is that the hot reload only seems to work when *unpausing*.
The problem is my project is not always *paused* when making changes.

Is there another way so I can bind a HotKey to it?

I am aware this is a detail, but pausing/unpausing takes unnecessary time and gets me a tiny bit out of the flow (pausing, VS interface shifting, waiting a few seconds, unpausing).

Comment: Are you referring to `dotnet watch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version (16.11.7) this is now possible within default Visual Studio.